# Why Shared service is not working with the components that do not have child parent relationship

Tags: javascript, angular, service, rxjs, electron

I have elctron app with Angular frontend.
You can think Electron as Chromium web browser, basically we are running our Angular app on Chromium web browser but in desktop window.

In my app-component I've input box and ok button so when user press the ok button I'm showing prompt-reason component on a entire  window. I'm directly loading this component in electron for example like we directly entering the URL in browser: loclhost:4200/promptInput

I want to share the app component input into the prompt-input component, so I've write following DataService, but it's not working, I didn't get why it's not working. And is there any other to pass data from app-component to prompt-input component ?

Code:
DataService 1:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private message: string = '';

  constructor() {}

  changeMessage(newMessage: string) {
    this.message = newMessage;
  }
  getMessage(): string {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

Data Service 2:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  // Use BehaviorSubject to handle the data and allow components to subscribe to changes
  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  // Expose the BehaviorSubject as an Observable for components to consume
  currentData: Observable<any> = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  changeData(data: any): void {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

  getCurrentData(): any {
    return this.dataSource.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show how the data is obtained from `DataService` in the component. A quick glance at data service 2 shows that you are returning the data synchronously, rendering the purpose of the `BehaviorSubject` useless. Ideally you'd return the observable here, and subscribe to it in the component. That way, each new emission would be obtained by the component.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may depend on how you are fetching the data in the prompt-input component, but I would suggest anyway to use DataService2 example, but changed to use the observable rather than the private subject variable. So you don't really need `getCurrentData` method, you just need the `currentData$` observable to which you need to subscribe inside the `prompt-input` component. In this way, whenever the `app-component` will call the `changeData` method and a new value will be emitted you will receive it in the `prompt-input` component. Hope this answer helps you.

Also, as a good practice, it's better to avoid using `any` as return type, better provide the exact return type whenever you can.